# Change background in R Markdown beamer presentation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I'm writing on a beamer presentation in rmarkdown and I have two types of frames which should differ by their background.
So I wrote two functions like that in latex:

```
\newcommand{\settitlestyle}{
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  \includegraphics[width = \paperwidth, height = \paperheight] 
{backgroundtitle.jpg}}
}
```

`\setmainstyle` is exactly the same command but another jpg.

In the YAML I have already input a tex file that defines the functions and calls `\settitlestyle`. Works. But after the first slide I want to switch to the mainstyle. When I call `\setmainstyle` in the markdownfile nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your `\setmainstyle` command is that it will be used inside a frame and thus be void.

To avoid this problem you could use the same strategy as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173201/beamer-template-with-different-style-options-for-frames to create a frame option which will change the background.

Unfortunately rmarkdown simply ignores user created frame options and only passes on a tiny list of predefined options. To trick rmarkdown one could repurpose a frame option which is normally not used by beamer, the `standout` frame option (it is only used by the metropolis theme)

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{etoolbox}

  \defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{mydefault}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}
  }
  \defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{standout}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,page=2]{example-image-duck}
  }

  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[mydefault]%
  }

  \makeatletter
  \define@key{beamerframe}{standout}[true]{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[standout]%
  }
  \makeatother

---

# frametitle 

test

# frametitle with different background {.standout}

test

# frametitle

test
```

[image]

or if you want to change the background for all following frames:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{mydefault}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,page=2]{example-image-duck}
}
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{standout}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}
}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[mydefault]%

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{standout}[true]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[standout]%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

#### Update:

Pandoc now allows arbitrary frame options (https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/7fbce82f2f7b69e88b23cf138ea6cd3a86786b91)

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
header-includes: |

  \defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{mydefault}{}
  \defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{special}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}
  }

  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[mydefault]%
  }

  \makeatletter
  \define@key{beamerframe}{special}[true]{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[special]%
  }
  \makeatother

---

# frametitle 

test

# Heading {frameoptions="special"}

test

# frametitle 

test
```

Comment: Works perfect. From man pandoc: All of the other frame attributes described in Section 8.1 of the Beamer User’s Guide may also be used (see list next comment)

Comment: allowdisplaybreaks, allowframebreaks, b, c, s, t, environment, label, plain, shrink, standout, noframenumbering, squeeze.