# Adding numbers to bibliography list in Rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bibtex, bibliography

I am using t latex to write my thesis via Rmarkdown. I am currently using a specific citation style from my University. I am trying to number my reference list whilst keeping citation. Does anyone know how to do this in Bibtex in markdown?

Here is what my Rmarkdwon/latex code looks like

```
---
title: 'My Title'
output: pdf_document
bibliography: bibliography.bib
csl: harvard-manchester-metropolitan-university.csl
---

# Background 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book[@debarsy_testing_2010]. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum [@lamichhane_spatial-temporal_2015].

\newpage

# References
```

Here is my `bibliography.bib` file looks like.

```
@article{debarsy_testing_2010,
    title = {Testing for spatial autocorrelation in a fixed effects panel data model},
    volume = {40},
    issn = {0166-0462},
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166046210000451},
    doi = {10.1016/j.regsciurbeco.2010.06.001},
    abstract = {The aim of this paper is to assess the relevance of spatial autocorrelation in a fixed effects panel data model and in the affirmative, to identify the most appropriate spatial specification as this appears to be a crucial point from the modeling perspective of interactive heterogeneity. Several {LM} test statistics as well as their {LR} counterparts, which allow discriminating between endogenous spatial lag versus spatially autocorrelated errors, are therefore proposed. Monte Carlo experiments show their good finite sample performance. Finally, an empirical application is provided in the framework of the well-known Feldstein–Horioka puzzle.},
    pages = {453--470},
    number = {6},
    journaltitle = {Regional Science and Urban Economics},
    shortjournal = {Regional Science and Urban Economics},
    author = {Debarsy, Nicolas and Ertur, Cem},
    urldate = {2015-10-01},
    date = {2010-11},
    keywords = {Panel data, Spatial autocorrelation, Test statistics},
    file = {complex_zotero_path}
}

@article{lamichhane_spatial-temporal_2015,
    title = {Spatial-Temporal Modeling of Neighborhood Sociodemographic Characteristics and Food Stores},
    volume = {181},
    issn = {0002-9262, 1476-6256},
    url = {http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/181/2/137},
    doi = {10.1093/aje/kwu250},
    abstract = {The literature on food stores, neighborhood poverty, and race/ethnicity is mixed and lacks methods of accounting for complex spatial and temporal clustering of food resources. We used quarterly data on supermarket and convenience store locations from Nielsen {TDLinx} (Nielsen Holdings N.V., New York, New York) spanning 7 years (2006–2012) and census tract-based neighborhood sociodemographic data from the American Community Survey (2006–2010) to assess associations between neighborhood sociodemographic characteristics and food store distributions in the Metropolitan Statistical Areas ({MSAs}) of 4 {US} cities (Birmingham, Alabama; Chicago, Illinois; Minneapolis, Minnesota; and San Francisco, California). We fitted a space-time Poisson regression model that accounted for the complex spatial-temporal correlation structure of store locations by introducing space-time random effects in an intrinsic conditionally autoregressive model within a Bayesian framework. After accounting for census tract–level area, population, their interaction, and spatial and temporal variability, census tract poverty was significantly and positively associated with increasing expected numbers of supermarkets among tracts in all 4 {MSAs}. A similar positive association was observed for convenience stores in Birmingham, Minneapolis, and San Francisco; in Chicago, a positive association was observed only for predominantly white and predominantly black tracts. Our findings suggest a positive association between greater numbers of food stores and higher neighborhood poverty, with implications for policy approaches related to food store access by neighborhood poverty.},
    pages = {137--150},
    number = {2},
    journaltitle = {American Journal of Epidemiology},
    shortjournal = {Am. J. Epidemiol.},
    author = {Lamichhane, Archana P. and Warren, Joshua L. and Peterson, Marc and Rummo, Pasquale and Gordon-Larsen, Penny},
    urldate = {2015-10-01},
    date = {2015-01-15},
    langid = {english},
    pmid = {25515169},
    keywords = {food availability, food stores, intrinsic conditionally autoregressive model, neighborhood characteristics, Poverty, sociodemographic factors, spatial-temporal modeling, supermarkets},
    file = {complex_zotero_path}
}
```

And you can get the `harvard-manchester-metropolitan-university.csl` styling from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj56M_Ik5LzAhUlDmMBHfmnAUgQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Fstyles%2Fharvard-manchester-metropolitan-university&usg=AOvVaw14SrlAai6Q1yUZxXYNe52y)

Comment: Please add a [mre] as text which we can copy and not as image

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have managed to include this now. Hope this is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are neither using bibtex nor biblatex, so one needs a bit of a hack to add numbers to the bibliography.

You could include the following file in your header:

```
\newcounter{foo}
\renewenvironment{CSLReferences}[2] % #1 hanging-ident, #2 entry spacing
 {% don't indent paragraphs
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  % turn on hanging indent if param 1 is 1
  \ifodd #1 \everypar{\stepcounter{foo}\thefoo.~\setlength{\hangindent}{\cslhangindent}}\ignorespaces\else\everypar{\stepcounter{foo}\thefoo.~}\fi
  % set entry spacing
  \ifnum #2 > 0
  \setlength{\parskip}{#2\baselineskip}
  \fi
 }%
 {}
```

[image]

Comment: As I'm new in RMD, how can I add the above file in the header?

Comment: @Lefty You can add it via header includes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644762/2777074 for an example who to add lengthy code to the header